# Redmine plugin - ScreenshotPaste not working on 2.0.4

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to install http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/PluginScreenshotPaste or Redmine 2.0.4, but, no luck.

Do somebody knows how to amend the plugin to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a rework of the plugin because it wasn't compatible with Redmine 2.1.x

You can checkout it on my github account : [redmine_screenshot_paste](https://github.com/undx/redmine_screenshot_paste).

I haven't tested it on branch 2.0.x. Please, tell me if it works or post an issue on github.

Comment: thanks it does not work on 2.0.4, i have opened an issue on github

Comment: Now fixed. Works with Redmine 2.x branch.